# Positioning DIVS push to the left most part

Tags: html, css

I am really confused in CSS positioning. I have a job posting and I want it to look like this.

```
PHP Developer      |        Company Logo
------------------------------------------
Job Desciption:

lorem ipsum etc etc etc

Salary: P10000
------------------------------------------
```

I want to push the company logo to the right without using float.

Here is my markup and my css:

```css
.job-post-title,
.job-post-company {
  display: inline-block;
}

.job-post-header {
  position: relative;
}

.job-post-title {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.job-post-title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="job-post">
  <div class="job-post-header">
    <div class="job-post-title">[title]</div>
    <div class="job-post-company">[picture]</div>
  </div>
  <div class="job-post-body">
    <div class="job-post-description">[body]</div>
    <div class="job-post-salary">[field_salary]</div>
    <div class="job-post-flag">[ops]</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update Your css Like this

```
.job-post-title,
.job-post-company {
  display: inline-block;
}

.job-post-header, .job-post-body{
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border-bottom:1px dashed #000;
}

.job-post-company {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.job-post-title {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  border-right:1px dashed #000;
}
```

Comment: It is good to add some explanation about the changes you made in the code.